# query windows "CD" dynamic env var from inside python

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

"CD" is apparently a "dynamic" environment variable in windows.  From inside python, it does not show up in os.environ dictionary; nor does it arrive when queried with os.getenv().  Is there a means of accessing this environment variable from inside python?

Before folks tell me to use os.getcwd(), please understand that os.getcwd() does not follow soft links.  On linux and mac, I can access the PWD environment variable to get the current directory including the soft linked directories.  I'm hoping to do something similar on windows as well, if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: By "soft link" do you mean "symbolic link", "junction point", or something else?

Comment: `echo %CD%` doesn't appear to display anything different from what I entered in my `cd` command, even when the path I specified has symbolic links in it (e.g. `Documents and Settings` is a symlink to `Users`). `cd` doesn't appear to support Windows shortcuts (`.lnk` files) at all. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @kindall Well, on Vista, `Documents and Settings` is an NTFS junction point, which is not quite the same as a symbolic link. The former shows up in `dir` as `<JUNCTION>`, and the latter as `<SYMLINK>` or `<SYMLINKD>`. But I don't see any difference between the returned values of `echo %CD%` and running `os.getcwd()` in Python.

Comment: "soft link" - yes, "symbolic link."   We have linux file servers mapped to particular drives on the windows machines.  The file servers  will use symbolic links the directory structures when they are deployed.  From the feedback, it sounds like CD is not the windows equivalent of PWD.

Comment: @MayurPatel Linux? That's completely different. If you're mapping linux symlinks via SMB... well... it depends how you're doing it. You'll have to be more specific about your setup, and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The working directory of a process on Windows is not an environment variable. It is read by calling the Win32 API function [`GetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934.aspx). In Python that is wrapped up by `os.getcwd()`.

There is no standard environment variable on Windows named `CD`. The command interpretor `cmd.exe` does create the illusion of an environment variable named `CD`, but it's private to `cmd.exe`. Since your code runs in the Python executable, that's just not relevant. Note that when you execute the `set` command in `cmd.exe`, there is no `CD` variable listed.

It's easy to verify that what I say is true. Write a simple C program that calls `GetEnvironmentVariable` passing `"CD"`. You'll see that there is no such variable.

Even if you did happen to be able to hack into the `cmd.exe` process that started your `Python` executable, what good would it do you. Your Python process has a working directory that is distinct from that of `cmd.exe`. And who says that your Python process was even started from `cmd.exe`?

I'm not quite certain where your confusion lies, but the way to obtain the working directory in Python is to call `os.getcwd()`. And then if you want to resolve symlinks, you will have to do so yourself.

Comment: FWIW, doing `echo %CD%` in `cmd.exe` does print what appears to be the CWD, but I'm guessing it's built-in to the shell, and not a true environment variable.

Comment: @aya That's a cmd.exe special.

Comment: @Mayur Are you looking for more info than this?